# Splitting the page in two sections

Tags: css, html, position

[image: What I am trying to achieve]I have a facebook app and I am working on the front-end now. I am just getting started with css and html, so this might be a silly question- sorry for that.
What I am trying to do is to divide the page in two sections. I've created two `div`s for that, but the problem is the way they are positioned. My code is the following:

```
<style>
.choose_div{
  width: 20%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 1px;
  left: 0px;
  border: 2px;
}
.frame_div{
  right:0px;
  height: auto;
  width: 80%;
  border: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
  position: relative;
}
</style>
  <div id="choose_div">
    <ul>
      <li class="li_choose">
        <div class="li_div">
          <p>Save</p>
            <img src="arrow.jpg" id="arrow_save" style="width:10%;height:10%">
           <hr>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
<div id="frame_div">
  <iframe id="frame_opened">
</div>
```

I thought that `right:0px;` for one and `left:0px;`for the other would position them properly, but they are just one at the bottom of the other.
Can anyone please help with this?

Comment: When you say "divide the page in two sections", what are you actually trying to achieve? Maybe an example or image might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the normal way to do what you ask, using `float:left;`. There were a few other issues with your styles though:

- You were targetting `.choose_div` the class (`.`), not the id (`#`)
- You need to use `box-sizing:border-box` when you're doing this otherwise the `padding` and `border` is added on top of `width:20%` making the width larger than 20%.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/SB9Y2/1/)

```
#choose_div {
    width: 20%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 1px;
    border: 2px;
    float:left;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
#frame_div {
    height: auto;
    width: 80%;
    border: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
    float:left;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

As for `left` and `right`, they can be used to align to a particular side of the screen if using `position:absolute`. `position:relative` simply shifts the element a particular amount, for example `left:2px` would shift the element 2 pixels to the left.

`position:absolute` positions the element on its closest ancestor that has a `position` of non-static. Then `left`/`right`/`top`/`bottom` can be used to indicate the sides of the ancestor.

Answer (score 1):

for the div which to be shown write:

```
float:left
```

And for the right one:

```
float:right

<style>
#choose_div{
  width: 20%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 1px;
  left: 0px;
  border: 2px;
  float:left;

}
#frame_div{
  float:right;
  right:0px;
  height: auto;
  width: 80%;
  border: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
  position: relative;
}
</style>
```

If you add borders you must shrink your divs' witdh. Or they overflows the parent section and seen top-bottom.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <style>
html,body{margin:0;}
#choose_div{
  display:block;
  float:left;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 1px;
  }
#frame_div{
 float:right;
 height: auto;
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
  border-left:solid 2px #000000;
  padding:10px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
    </style>
    <body>

      <div id="choose_div">
        <ul>
          <li class="li_choose">
            <div class="li_div">
              <p>Save</p>
                <img src="arrow.jpg" id="arrow_save" style="width:10%;height:10%">
                 </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    <div id="frame_div">
      <iframe id="frame_opened">
    </div>
```